# Loading System.Net.Http in 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.net.httpwebrequest

I wish to use "System.Net.Http" on the client server that is running .net 4.0.

In my bin i have "System.Net.Http.dll" and yet receive the following error

[image]

In my web.config i have

```
<add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
```

Upgrading the server is not an option

-- EDIT --

It's worth noting the client server does not have MVC installed. This is a light-weight webforms application.

Comment: 4.0 is no longer supported. The minimum supported version is 4.5.2. You *have* to upgrade the server because TLS1.2 was added in 4.5.2. Many sites and services have already dropped support for SSL v3 and even TLS 1.1. Some (very big) services require TLS 1.2 from January 2016 onwards

Comment: that is why i couldn't the dll which i got from nuget Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http